# Finite dimensional subspaces of L^p, entropy estimates

Tags: reference-request, banach-spaces, entropy

The following follows from Proposition 9.6 in Approximation of zonoids by zonotopes, Acta Math. 162 (1989), no. 1-2, 73–141, by Bourgain, J., Lindenstrauss, J., and Milman, V.

Let $X\subset L^1(\mu)$ be a n-dimensional subspace, where $\mu$ is a probability measure. There exists an isometry $L^1(\mu)\mapsto L^1(\widetilde\mu)$, which is pretty explicit, such that (denoting by $\widetilde X$ the image of $X$ under the isometry)
$$\log E(B_{\widetilde X}^1, tB_{\widetilde X}^2)\leq C\phi(t)n \quad\text{for every $t>1$},$$
for some absolute constant $C$ and some function $\phi$ such that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\phi(t) = 0$ (e.g., $\phi(t) = \frac{\log(1+t)}{t^2}$, but I only care about the fact that it vanishes).

Notation:
$$B_{\widetilde X}^p = \{f\in \widetilde X\colon \|f\|_{L^p(\widetilde\mu)} \leq 1\},$$
$$E(B_{\widetilde X}^1, tB_{\widetilde X}^2) = \min\{\# k\colon B_{\widetilde X}^1 \subseteq\bigcup_{j=1}^k(x_j + tB_{\widetilde X}^2)\quad\text{for $x_j\in B_{\widetilde X}^1$}\}.$$

**Reference I'm looking for:**

I'm looking for a reference for its generalization (assuming such a generalization is true) to the case where $p=1$ is replaced by any $p\in[1,2)$, that is, a reference for the following statement.

Let $p\in[1, 2)$ and $X\subset L^p(\mu)$ be a n-dimensional subspace, where $\mu$ is a probability measure. There exists an isometry $L^p(\mu)\mapsto L^p(\widetilde\mu)$ such that
$$\log E(B_{\widetilde X}^p, tB_{\widetilde X}^2)\leq C\phi(t)n,$$
for some absolute constant $C = C(p)$ and some function $\phi$ such that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\phi(t) = 0$.

**What I have found and tried:**

After studying their proof, I think that such a generalization should be possible, but my knowledge of entropy estimates and finite dimensional subspaces of $L^p$ is superficial, unfortunately, and there are some points in their proof I don't fully understand.

The closest result that I could find is Proposition 3.1 in Embedding subspaces of $L^p$ into $\ell_p^N$, Math. Nachr. 227 (2001), 133–142, by Schechtman, G. and Zvavitch, A. However, only a weaker estimate is proved there, namely, for $p\in(0,2)$ (I'm interested only in the range $p\in[1,2)$, though),
$$\log E(B_{\widetilde X}^p, tB_{\widetilde X}^2)\leq C\phi(t)n\log n\quad\text{for every $t>1$}.$$

I would be grateful for any references or hints.

Comment: If $p\in [1,2]$, the space $L_p[0,1]$ is isometric to a subspace of $L_1[0,1]$, so you get the same $L_1$ entropy estimates for every $p\in [1,2]$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me! I didn't realize that.